# Docker-machine - IP address conflict

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Here are my environment:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Docker for windows

When I create new machine, I encounter the IP address conflict:

[image: IP Address conflict]

And the console is stuck at phase starting VM

```
Creating VirtualBox VM... 
Creating SSH key... 
Starting VirtualBox VM... 
Starting VM...
```

Furthermore, when I press Ctrl-C to stop the script and run **eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"**, I receive following error:

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
open C:\Users\jacob.phan\.docker\machine\machines\dev\ca.pem: The system cannot
find the file specified.
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? 
$ boot2docker delete
$ boot2docker download
$ boot2docker init

Comment: OP: Has you tried to look in the Windows System event log?
@AlexandreNucera OP is not using boot2docker

Comment: Alexandre Nucera: delete-download-init doesn't help
@Kevin Simper: There's an error in Event Log: "The system detected an address conflict for IP address 192.168.99.1 with the system having network hardware address 08-00-27-7D-49-65. Network operations on this system may be disrupted as a result."

Comment: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1573 Using CIDR environment option was a work-around for me.

Comment: do you have Oracle VirtualBox installed? if yes, have you seen Docker auto-generated a VM named "default"?

Comment: I have the same problem. Linh, I can see that Docker auto-generated the "default" vm and it is running. I have no idea how to work around this issue though.

Comment: please attach the network output, i met this before with the issue written in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling for this problem for a while, in the end, i notice it there is  wrong network interface created in boot2docker for new VM:

If you have network different than this, then try to check your network configuration.

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6198:761d:eec:5394%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I had one wrong VirtualBox DHCP Network created at that time, which cause the problem. When I deleted, everything goes fine